# Django ModelForm field queryset based on another field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Consider my `models.py`,

**PowerPolicy**:

```py
class PowerPolicy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ...
```

**Group**:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   #But then, we also have:
   power_policies = models.ManytoManyField(PowerPolicy)
```

**Player**:

```py
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

And then another model called,

**UsePower**:

```py
class UserPower(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    power_policy = models.ForeignKey(PowerPolicy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

**But!** Here's the catch:  I want to make it so that my **superuser** *(Note that my superuser isn't a player, he's simply a superuser)* can only create a `UsePower` object of the `Power`s specified in the `Player`'s `Group`. Now, I do know that I have to create a custom form and override the queryset of the `power_policy` field that returns, my the custom queryset according to my needs through a function.

 - Here's what it would look something like:

```py
class UsePowerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UsePowerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def MyCustomFunctionThatReturnsTheQuerySet():
            This function returns the Power policies that are allowed to the player in
            their player Group. The only problem is,
            Our little function here doesn't know how to get the player chosen.
                could you help
            return TheQuerySet

        self.fields['power_policy'].queryset = MyCustomFunctionThatReturnsTheQuerySet()
```

And then use it on the Admin Site, by doing this:

```py
class UsePowerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UsePowerForm

admin.site.register(UsePower, UsePowerForm)
```

I really hope this makes sense, and you guys could help me out.

Thank you for your time reading this, I honestly do appreciate it.

**EDIT:** Using form cleaning, or verifying during save, is not an option for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the player when the form is being initialized:

```
class UserPowerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UsePowerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        player = Player.objects.get(id=self.initial['player'])

        ###from here you can use player to get the power policies and put into list

        self.fields['power_policy'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=power_policy_list)


    class Meta:
        model = UserPower
        fields = ['player', 'power_policy']
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain this code a bit, like how would I use it in my case? And what does it do? Because you say get the "player" when the "form is being initialized". What does that mean? I will choose the Player inside the form. Not before the form..

Comment: I was under the impression that you will pass an UsePower instance to the form.[Here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) is a detailed tutorial on how to create dependent dropdown list. Enjoy.

Comment: Oh now I see. That makes a lot of sense. But they're using custom views and Ajax for doing that, is there a way to just, do it inside the plain old Django Admin, without rendering a view?

Comment: check out [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#using-autocompletes-in-the-admin)

Comment: And there we go. Thank You! :)